# Fetch all posts when going back to the list view

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Settings**

Assume there are two view controllers: `PostsVC` and `PostDetailVC`. In `PostsVC` there are 100 posts loaded. Each post shows its body, author, and number of comments.

**Problem**

When the user first opens the app, 100 posts are fetched from the API server. Then he can go to one of the posts and comment on it. He goes back to `PostsVC` and realizes the number of comments is still `0`.

**My Solution**

`PostsVC` can have an observer that listens to `updateNumComment` for a certain post. Then, in `PostDetailVC`, I can notify that there has been a change in the number of comments.

**Naive Solution**

Every time you go back to `PostsVC` I can just fetch the latest `posts` information from the API server (done in `viewWillAppear`). However, since only one of the 100 posts was updated, it's a waste of network resources.

**Confusion**

Naive solution seems to work pretty well. I can't tell whether it's fetching 100 posts or just 1 post. *My solution* can get complicated if there are more information to synchronize, such as number of comments, number of votes, number of users who commented, etc. Is **My solution** not necessary? Am I overthinking the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question of optimizing your user experience while minimizing your network usage.

Since you already know that your naïve solution is a waste of network resources then that is what you want to avoid.

The question then becomes how can you update your UI while minimizing server calls. You have stated that in your new solution you want to use an observer in `PostsVC` to pick up the changes on comments and other details. There is extra overhead in managing an observer such as registration and removal.

My recommendation is to instead declare a delegate protocol in your `PostDetailVC`, where I am assuming this is where comments are being entered, and have `PostsVC` conform to this protocol. When a comment is added, call the delegate method to notify the `PostsVC` of the changes so the UI can be updated immediately by incrementing the comment count.

You can then synchronize your local data with the server data on a background thread. In the completion block of the network request that updates the comment, update the last updated date for the post as a way to minimize future network requests.